# Help with shading error (NPR material, EEVEE shader + png texture overlays)

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, npr

[rendering on CUDA. GeForce RTX 2080ti + AMD Ryzen 9 3900X]

I'm having an issue with a ganon model I'm making for a friend. I have this weird pixelation overlay on certain parts of the model. I can't find if it's an issue with the model itself, the NPR material that I have transparent images overlaid onto or something else. I'm relatively new to this whole thing. I tried to omit the png overlay textures from the node tree but the pixel overlay still happens. The nips are a png texture (that also is overlaying weirdly with a white border,) and the scar on his sternum is made with a normal map and a png.

[image: Ganon model with the screwy pixel overlay.]

**The pixel overlay I'm talking about is on the right part of the chest, lower lip and extends to the abdomen.**

[Here's a dl for the .blend file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10cAGDeA9GfJEhfxjVb4HglKEerS-yVCM/view?usp=sharing)

Also I'm really sorry how terrible my model alterations are, UV's and my texture work, it's still a heavy work in progress. I would start all over but I'm really happy with how I edited the MakeHuman sculpt so I'm overly hesitant to do so.

Comment: Seems like you havent included the textures files.Pack it with all files and uploading would help in understanding the issue...  Also, since you have said you used some transparent pngs in that, make sure those are free of unwanted marks in those areas, it could be just the problem with the image itself

Comment: @Suhas I've re-packed the .blend file. My apologies for not including all files to beging with. Thank you for the advice. I'd redone the transparent files a few times to absolutely make sure there was no residue leftover- and didn't see any change.

Comment: Sorry! I dont see anything as such when I downloaded the file and viewed the model in render view! .. so I don't think its any issue with the png files.. So I cant help anymore. But you can try deleting the material and then try recreating the same..bcz it might be a one time bug/issue..